# Howto - reference within module to value exported by module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've created a node module for declaring value's that i use like constants (I'm a js/node newbie, coming from statically typed languages)...

```
module.exports = {
  HELLO : "hello",

  BLAH_VAL : "blahv",
  BLAH_OBJ : {
    type : "blahtype",
    value : BLAH_VAL        // syntax error
    value2 : this.BLAH_VAL    // doesn't work
  },
  // etc.
};
```

The problem is the "value : BLAH_VAL".  What I want is for this to be interpreted as *value : "blahv"*, but without repeating the literal string.  I get a syntax error, which goes away if I use "value : this.BLAH", but then 'value' dissapears completely.

Or maybe I need to define the simple values in one module and the compound types in a 2nd module that references the first?

I'm using Node 4.3.2 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using JSON format, use functions to create an object and attach to module.exports.

The following should work:

```
function constants() {

    this.HELLO = "hello";
    this.BLAH_VAL = "blahv";
    this.BLAH_OBJ = {
        type : "blahtype",
        value2 : this.BLAH_VAL
    };

};

module.exports = new constants();
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your intention. Thanks

Comment: Very good, thanks - I'll do it that way, though I worry that doing it as a function will make it slower.  I guess with js I need to just stop worrying about such things!

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it requires extra code so I don't consider it optimal and am hoping someone else will post a better solution.

```
var BLAH_VAL_TEXT = "blahv";

module.exports = {
  BLAH_VAL : BLAH_VAL_TEXT;
  BLAH_OBJ : {
    type : "blahtype",
    value : BLAH_VAL_TEXT
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need object. So make object factory!

```
function SettingsFactory() {
  var BLAH_VAL_TEXT = "blahv";
  return {
    BLAH_VAL: BLAH_VAL_TEXT,
    BLAH_OBJ: {
      type: "blahtype",
      value: BLAH_VAL_TEXT
    }
  }
}

module.exports = SettingsFactory();
```

Also look at [typescript](http://typescriptlang.org/). It is JS with strict types and new features from ES6-7

Comment: Yes, good suggestion - the prospect of typescript made me more open to trying javascript, and I plan to try it, but I thought I would try js plain while I waited for greater TS adoption.